# I want to display an image in ADF table row when it's true and hide it when it's false, knowing that the row attribute returns 0 ,1

Tags: oracle-adf

I want to display an image in ADF table row when it's true and hide it when it's false, knowing that the row attribute returns 0 ,1 as in Boolean.
I'm using  Active Image.

Answer (score 1):

I can be accomplished using the rendered attribute.  That might look something like:

```
<af:table value="#{bindings.SomeView1.collectionModel}" var="row">
  <af:column>
     <af:outputText value="imgs in next columnc displayed conditionally">
  <af:column/>
  <af:column>
     <af:activeImage source="/myPath/myImg.gif"
                     rendered="#{row.someAttribute == '1'}">
  <af:column/>
  <af:column>
     <af:image source="/myPath/myImg.gif"
               rendered="#{row.someAttribute == '1'}">
  <af:column/>
<af:table>
```

Note that, unless you are have an Active Data Service set up and configured, you should be using `<af:image>` instead of `<af:activeimage>` (see component documentation).

Answer (score 0):

Codemonk's logic is correct, but Visible is a better attribute to use for this than rendered.

[Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/adf/tag-reference-faces/tagdoc/af_image.html):
Default Value: true

the visibility of the component. If it is "false", the component will be hidden on the client. **Unlike "rendered", this does not affect the lifecycle on the server - the component may have its bindings executed, etc. - and the visibility of the component can be toggled on and off on the client, or toggled with PPR.** When "rendered" is false, the component will not in any way be rendered, and cannot be made visible on the client. In most cases, use the "rendered" property instead of the "visible" property.

We frequently reserve "rendered" for security use cases when we do not want the markup generated into the page. Visible turns it on and off with html/markuup already on the page.